# How to redirect from action state to view state on success in Spring web flow

Tags: spring

How to redirect from action state to view state on success in Spring web flow.

```
<action-state id="searchTabAction">
        <evaluate
            expression="ccdiSearchAction.search(flowRequestContext,flowScope.metadataHandle)" />
        <transition on="success" to="..." />
        <transition on="error" to="errorEndState" />
    </action-state>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/actions.html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <var name="taskId" class="java.lang.String" />

    <action-state id="myAction">
        <evaluate expression="taskId!=null" />
        <transition on="no" to="task_unavailable" />
        <transition on="yes" to="task_detail" />
    </action-state>

    <view-state id="task_detail" view="task_detail.xhtml" />

    <end-state id="task_unavailable" view="task_unavailable" />

</flow>
```